# Show/hide navigation bar when searchcontroller is set

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application where I need the navigation bar on only the listing screen and not the detailed screen (in most cases). I can easily achieve this by hiding the navbar in the detail screen using

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false) //Added in viewWillAppear
```

Optionally, the listing screen also allows the user to search on tapping a button.

When the user taps on the search button, I add a searchController to the navigation bar

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = mySearchController
```

At this point if I take the user to the detailed view, the navigation bar does not hide on the detailed view. I tried adding the code to hide the navbar in `viewDidAppear:` and it works but shows a strange transition from navbar to no-navbar.

How can I get the navigation bar to hide in the detailed view when the searchcontroller is set in the previous screen? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As from what I understand from your question is you want to hide navigation bar on detail view and show it again when you are in master view (let's say), if that is the case I would do something like this in the detail view

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Edit
**Please be aware that with this implementation you will lose swipe back functionality**

Comment: I can do that. The problem is when I have a search bar in the navigation bar. In that case, calling setNavigationBarHidden doesn't hide the nav bar unless called in viewDidAppear (please see the question for more details)